# Rails: set up polymorphic associations for two user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations, user-roles

I'm starting to code a linkedin-like website in Rails for my thesis that would enable members to post job offers (employers) and other members (employees) to respond to them.

I've been trying to wrap my head around the data model and associations - because I don't want to have two channels of authentication for emploYers and Yees - I want to keep email, nickname and password in one table (model) and use that for logging in, and then from there go to Employer and Employee specific data.

I was reading about STI but I figured that Yer has very different data than Yee and there would be a lot of nulls in the Users table, which isn't quite an optimal thing I suppose.

Then I've stumbled across polymorphic associations, but I don't really know how to set them up.
I was thinking of something like this:

```
User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :employer, polymorphic: true
  has_one :employee, polymorphic: true
end

Employee < ApplicationRecord
end

Employer < ApplicationRecord
end
```

My head boils cause I don't know what's the best way to achieve this, any tips much appreciated,
cheers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the polymorphic association here.

```
User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :employer
  has_one :employee

  def employer?
    employer.present?
  end

  def employee?
    employee.present?
  end
end
```

Not sure if this would be the best solution in your case though.